# Tracking files/folders changes

Tags: linux, file, filesystems

I have a tree of files and folders mounted in a mount point. The mount point can be accessed from several machines.

Is there a way I can create some sort of "index" of files and folder in such a way that after some random amount of time (and some FS operations in that mount point) I can create another "index" and compare it to the first one?

What I want to achieve is some sort of "git log" that would let me know what happened in that mount point between the first and the second "index", e.g. which files got renamed, deleted, created, which folders got moved to another location, etc...

There are some notes:

- I can't use inotify or anything similar. The method should be able to work "offline", meaning that there might be changes in the folders struture while the system is down.
- I can't use git (or equivalent). This must be fully automated solution. Using a CVS would require me to further do "git add ." (or similar), committing, etc... I know it's possible to automate git, but that's not the point of my question.

Comment: I do this using some code I wrote in C, which recursively explores a filesystem and writes a row in a SLQLite3 database containing file metadata. Each new pass compares the current filesystem contents with the metadata stored by the previous pass, and can log differences, etc. With careful indexing, the database operations can be made tolerably fast. I struggle a little with the concept of "moving"  a file -- some heuristics are needed to guess when a file has been moved, rather one file deleted and another created. Storing some sort of file checksum might help, but that could be slow.

Comment: @KevinBoone Interesting. I was about to implement the same idea. As for the "move" operations, I'm looking at CRC32, which is quite fast and chances that "real world files" would collide in CRC32 are really really low.

Comment: The files I was working on were huge. However, I imagine that with a bit of imagination I could have worked out a mechanism where I only had to checksum part of each file. I guess there's likely to be a bit of a trade-off between speed and accuracy.

Comment: The inode number of the file remains the same if it was 'moved' anywhere on the same file system, so that could be captured and used instead of comparing checksums to detect renames.